# ConfigurationErrors Exception Error when try to console write connection string

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio

I started learning cloud computing with C#.

Right now, I am trying to console write the connection string from azure cloud: which is in xml config, to make sure my code is running properly before I connect the cloud.

When I run this, I get the error saying `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration system failed to initialize'`.

My guess is there is something wrong with my xml config, but I am not sure.

What did I do wrong here?

### program.cs

```cs
using My_Program.DataAccess;
using System;

namespace My_Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var readConfig = new ReadConfigration();
            var connString = readConfig.RadConfig();

            Console.WriteLine(connString);
        }
    }
}
```

### DataAccesss/ReadConfiguration.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace My_Program.DataAccess
{
    public class ReadConfigration
    {
        public string RadConfig()
        {
            string connectionString = "";

            foreach(ConnectionStringSettings settings in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
            {
                connectionString = settings.ConnectionString;
            }

            return connectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

### DataAccesss/App.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <appSettings>
    <add
        name="employeeAzurePreviewDatabase"
        providedName ="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="Server=tcp:myserver-demo1.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=day-1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=CloudSAd742343E3;Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
         
         />
        </appSettings>
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

### Error

[image]

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll
Configuration system failed to initialize
```

Comment: In `App.config`, you have set the value in `appsettings ` and reading the value as connectionstring in `.cs` file.

Comment: It has to be read as , `string con=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Value"];`

Comment: Or move the connection string to `,<ConnectionString>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The connection string you have set in `App.config` has be under
  `<connectionStrings>` tag.

***My App.config with Connectionstring tag***

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="empAzureDB"
      providerName ="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Server=tcp:myserver-demo1.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=day-1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=CloudSAd742343E3;Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then code you have written in `ReadConfiguration.cs` will work.

If you want to add the settings and read from `appsettings` tag, then it has to be like below

***My App.config with appsettings tag***

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration> 
 <appSettings>  
   <add key="empAzureDB"
     value="Server=tcp:myserver-demo1.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=day-1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=CloudSAd742343E3;Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"/>
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

***In ReadConfiguration.cs***

```cs
string myappset = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["empAzureDB"];
```

***Output***

[image]